# Web socket support for Microsoft IIS (ISAPI redirector + AJPv13) + Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, iis, spring-websocket, ajp

In one of our projects we wanted to start using web socket in a spring boot application and wanted to know if web socket are supported in our deployment model. We use IIS as web server which is configured to use ISAPI redirector and AJPv13 connector to proxy the requests to Tomcat. When we try a web socket request directly to tomcat on port 8080, everything is working fine. But, when we try the websocket request via IIS, we get the following error. Please let us know, if this is supported.

```
    2019-06-12 00:01:09,471 ERROR [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-3] 
    [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] 
    Forwarding to error page from request [/skinpack] due to exception 
    [Uncaught failure for request http://172.30.3.200/creatorportal/skinpack; 
    nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
    HTTP upgrade is not supported by this protocol] 

    org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeFailureException: 
    Uncaught failure for request http://172.30.3.200/creatorportal/skinpack; 
nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
HTTP upgrade is not supported by this protocol 
                        at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.java:175) 
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53) 
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) 
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) 
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) 
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) 
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) 
                        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) 
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
                        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) 
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) 
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) 
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
                        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130) 
                        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) 
                        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) 
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
                        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) 
                        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:488) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:685) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) 
                        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:394) 
                        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) 
                        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764) 
                        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388) 
                        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) 
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
                        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
        Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: HTTP upgrade is not supported by this protocol 
                        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.doHttpUpgrade(AbstractProcessor.java:824) 
                        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:566) 
                        at org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:432) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.upgrade(Request.java:2005) 
                        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.upgrade(RequestFacade.java:1123) 
                        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.UpgradeUtil.doUpgrade(UpgradeUtil.java:235) 
                        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.doUpgrade(WsServerContainer.java:263) 
                        at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.upgradeInternal(TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:72) 
                        at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.upgrade(AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.java:136) 
                        at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.AbstractHandshakeHandler.doHandshake(AbstractHandshakeHandler.java:279) 
                        at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.java:167) 
                        ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Comment: "We use IIS as web server which is configured to use ISAPI redirector and AJPv13 connector to proxy the requests to Tomcat." Microsoft does not support such setup. Java on IIS is only supported by HttpPlatformHandler, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manjug/2015/11/27/understanding-iis-httpplatformhandler-using-tomcat-8/ or you use ARR to set up a reverse proxy.

Comment: "Microsoft does not support such setup" - Is this about websockets?

Comment: “ISAPI redirector and AJPv13 connector” are not supported by Microsoft, so they are not guaranteed to work with IIS.

Comment: Thanks for the info Lex Li!! That set-up has been working for us for http requests so far.So, was wondering if this is just an issue with websockets.